# How can I make spaces after numbers stay in place in HTML?

Tags: html

I am having an issue with double spaces after dotted numbers as follows.

Suppose I put the following text in HTML, I get a space issue.

1.  Box 1

The output should be:

1. Box 1

However, I get the following:

1. Box 1

Even when using margins, I get the same problem.

An actual example is below.

In Word:Permanent deletion:

1. Click on the drop-down menu that displays, ‘Keep in Inbox’.
2. Click on, ‘Discard’, on the menu.

In HTML:
Permanent deletion:

1. Click on the drop-down menu that displays, ‘Keep in Inbox’.
2. Click on, ‘Discard’, on the menu.

Same text but in HTML.
How can I retain the second space after the number for each instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one space in html, you need to use the non-breaking space character entity

```
&nbsp;
```